# sql query for getting all the numbers of a group except minimum one

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table XYZ which contains data as below:-

```
ID  PNO   SEQ
10  2345    1
12  1234    1
13  4567    2
15  1234    3
16  5436    4
21  1324    5
26  5675    5
27  3423    5
29  6864    5
31  2432    6
```

Now I need output of the query as rows which contains duplicate SEQ but excluding the minimum ID of the SEQ.The output should be:-

```
ID  PNO    SEQ
12  1234    1
26  5675    5
27  3423    5
29  6864    5
```

I tried using the below query.It worked according to me but I need to optimize it.Please help in reducing the cost.

```
select ID,PNO,SEQ
FROM XYZ
WHERE SEQ IN
(SELECT SEQ
 FROM XYZ
 GROUP BY SEQ having count(*) > 1)
 and ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID) from XYZ  GROUP BY SEQ)
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? (As reported by running `select * from v$version`)

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify your query is using window functions.

```
SELECT id,pno,seq
FROM (SELECT x.*
      ,count(*) over(partition by seq) as cnt_per_seq
      ,min(id) over(partition by seq) as min_id_per_seq
      FROM XYZ x
     ) x
WHERE cnt_per_seq > 1 AND id <> min_id_per_seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  One is sufficient.  For your exact query:

```
SELECT ID, PNO, SEQ
FROM (SELECT XYZ.*, MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SEQ) as min_seq
      FROM XYZ
     ) t
WHERE id > MIN(ID);
```

For a given `SEQ`, a row is selected only when there are multiple values for the `SEQ`.

It is also worth checking if this is faster:

```
select id, pno, seq
from xyz
where id > (select min(xyz2.id) from xyz xyz2 where xyz2.seq = xyz.seq);
```

Oracle has a pretty good optimizer, so the performance might be pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show all records for which exists another record with the same `seq` and a smaller `id`:

```
select *
from xyz
where exists (select * from xyz other where other.seq = xyz.seq and other.id  < xyz.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SELECT ID,
       PNO,
       SEQ
FROM   (
  SELECT x.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY seq ORDER BY ID ) AS rn
  FROM   XYZ
)
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The programmatically simplest way is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.PNO, a.SEQ
FROM XYZ a
JOIN XYZ b on a.SEQ = b.SEQ AND a.ID > b.ID
```

This also only selects duplicates.